# Facebook and Parse integration unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to integrate a Facebook login with my Parse backend.  Upon running the app, I receive

> [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to class xxxxxx

on the line

```
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(nil)
```

or

```
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

I have tried the solution here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#unrecognizedselector
(adding the -ObjC flag), and have cleared Derived Data, to no avail.

I'm using Parse SDK 1.7.2, Facebook SDK 4.0.1, and the PFFacebookUtilesV4 framework.

The full error is as follows:

> 2015-05-03 14:22:25.742 hotPotato[49116:1453068] +[PFFacebookUtils
>   initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to class 0x10f524048 2015-05-03 14:22:25.810
>   hotPotato[49116:1453068] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[PFFacebookUtils
>   initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to class 0x10f524048'

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue.
My mistake was that I also added `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` in the project.

Just remove it and everything will be fine :)

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thanks @zurakach

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have imported the correct frameworks into your bridging header:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

Also check that the needed frameworks are included in the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** list under your target's **General** tab.

If you've added the frameworks manually, go to the **Build Settings** tab, and make sure that **Search Paths** contains the paths to the Parse and Facebook frameworks.
Mine looks something like this:

```
$(inherited)
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/Facebook
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/Parse
```

The `PFFacebookUtils` initialization call in the `application(application:, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` delegate method should follow the Parse initialization method:

```
Parse.setApplicationId("<APP_ID>", clientKey:"<CLIENT_KEY>")
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

If you haven't done this already, I suggest that you consult Parse's own guide:

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-setup/iOS

Comment: I have tried everything here, and my app was working very recently.  The only thing I have changed since it last worked was I moved the Parse library files, but I have re-added them and reset the search paths.

Comment: @milesper It would be really helpful if you could paste the whole `unrecognized selector` line.

Comment: Which part?  The entire line of code is posted; do you mean the error?

Comment: @milesper Try hovering over the specific path setting under Build Settings, the paths should be expanded in the tooltip.

Comment: The Framework Search Paths?  I can double click on them to expand them

Comment: Open the terminal and in the project directory run `xcodebuild -project <PROJECT_NAME> -scheme <SCHEME> -showBuildSettings|grep FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76941/discussion-between-milesper-and-bojan-dimovski).

Comment: Ok I'm going to award the bounty to this answer because it has good advice, but my problem is still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by making all my frameworks including my Parse ones referenced instead of copied.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late but I solved this by using the `Bolts.framework` from the Facebook SDK as opposed to the Parse SDK.